# probleme in audio player in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

help me in solve this error in audio player in flutter
"
Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.10.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.

The current Dart SDK (3.0.6) only supports null safety.

For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
"

i try deferente version of this audio player like 0.18.0
i expecting i good version of this audio player to solve this error

Comment: Can you also share some errors / warning during the build process ?